# Compiling C++ program on Windows XP

Tags: c++, windows

I have a problem running a simple Hello-world program in C++ on my Windows XP. I have written a post here:

> [Using the g++ C++ compiler from cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602937/using-the-g-c-compiler-from-cygwin)

where I stated the problem and I received many helpful replies, which solved some things. However, I still cannot run my hello-world program. Please, have a look at the post, I have included the program there. A friend of mine is able to run this program on his machine without problems. So, the problem should be in my system or libraries or something else, but I cannot figure what. In the "Edited" section of my post, I have included what error messages exactly I get.

Here is what I receive when I try to compile the program like this:

> g++ hello.cpp

From the cygwin shell:

When I try g++ hello.cpp, I get:

```
hello.cpp:1: parse error before character 0357
hello.cpp: In function 'int main()':
hello.cpp:'cout' undeclared (first use this function)
hello.cpp: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
hello.cpp: for each function it appears in.)
hello.cpp: 'endl' undeclared (first use this function)
g++.exe: hello.cpp: No such file or directory
g++.exe: No input files
g++.exe: hello.cpp: No such file or directory
g++.exe: No input files
g++.exe: hello.cpp: No such file or directory
g++.exe: No input files
g++.exe: hello.cpp: No such file or directory
g++.exe: No input files
g++.exe: hello.cpp: No such file or directory
g++.exe: No input files
```

And here is what I get when I try to compile the program (again with g++ hello.cpp) from the DOS command prompt:

When I try g++ hello.cpp, I get:

```
hello.cpp:1: parse error before character 0357
hello.cpp: In function 'int main()':
hello.cpp:'cout' undeclared (first use this function)
hello.cpp: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
hello.cpp: for each function it appears in.)
hello.cpp: 'endl' undeclared (first use this function)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have somehow got an illegal character in your code. Did you type the code in yourself or copy & paste it? If the latter, the source you copied from may be suspect in some way - type the code into the editor yourself, save it and recompile.

Answer (score 2):

You have an illegal character in your code; it may be caused by a bad character encoding or something like that. Try to check that.